# Geth --rpcaddr doubt

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, rpc

Can you tell me the differences between

--rpcaddr 127.0.0.1

--rpcaddr 0.0.0.0

--rpcaddr my_public_ip

--rpcaddr my_private_ip

during a private network config?

Thank you

Comment: That's more a networking question. If you don't know what is 127.0.0.1 then you have to read TCP/IP guide.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`--rpcaddr 127.0.0.1` starts the JSON RCP on the `localhost` network and only connections from your local machine reach the `geth` server

`--rpcaddr 0.0.0.0` starts the JSON RPC on all interfaces and any network can initiate the connection to your `geth` server

If you need to allow connections only from the localhost network you should use `127.0.0.1`

If you need to allow connections from your local network you should use your network ip (usually something like `192.168.1.1`)

If you're going to use `0.0.0.0` anybody can connect to your server

Comment: Can you set multiple IPs by repeating --rpcaddr like this:
`--rpcaddr localhost --rpcaddr 10.20.30.40`?